# how to verify payment paypal on mobile sdk 2.x?

Tags: mobile, paypal

i made application on android with paypal for payment but i donot know how to verify payment paypal in my app android.
this is my responce payment from paypal on sanbox environment.

```
{
     "response": {
         "state": "approved",
         "id": "PAY-27N978063W077501JKPUBNZQ",
         "create_time": "2014-08-11T01:05:42Z",
         "intent": "sale"
     },
     "client": {
         "platform": "Android",
         "paypal_sdk_version": "2.2.2",
         "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
         "environment": "sandbox"
     },
     "response_type": "payment"
 }
 {
     "amount": "520.10",
     "short_description": "htc one",
     "details": {
         "tax": "0.300000011920928955078125",
         "subtotal": "519.80",
         "shipping": "0"
     },
     "intent": "sale",
     "currency_code": "AUD",
     "item_list": {
         "items": [
             {
                 "quantity": "2",
                 "price": "259.90",
                 "sku": "GATE5000k",
                 "currency": "AUD",
                 "name": "htc one"
             }
         ]
     }
 }
```

please help me if you know the solution to resolve that?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into [documentation to verify payment](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/). It should guide you step by step to call the paypal rest api with your payment id and the steps you need to verify, namely that the state is approved and transaction details match.

Comment: yes, i have read it from here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/.
so now, i want to know when i can get money when i click capture button on paypal?
if i understand right. i can capture by the way request to rest api without login in paypal?

Comment: You should not need login to paypal for verification. After getting the client_id/client_secret following [these instructions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/make-your-first-call/), you make a get request on the payment. The "approved" state on the payment and the "completed" state on the sale means that the money is ready to be transferred to your (i.e. the merchants) account.

Comment: i got payment from link https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/<pay_id> and paypal responce
state: "approved",
intent: "sale",
sale: {
id: "8Y6046254R462893H",
create_time: "2014-08-26T08:19:21Z",
update_time: "2014-08-26T08:19:23Z",
amount: {
total: "260.20",
currency: "USD"
},
state: "completed",

Comment: You should now be able to log into https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/ with the sandbox paypal account you created and view transaction history. What you are doing is correct, but you do need to carry out the transactions in live and not sandbox to see actual money being transferred.

Comment: i want to make sure that i received money in my accound on paypal. because i have to update my bill when user bye product in my app.
this is my detail payment on sandbox https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ohaSCmGm8yE/U_0ubUPiowI/AAAAAAAACtw/-aZiJoFwQfI/w955-h404-no/Untitled.png

Comment: @DungQuang the payment id: "8Y6046254R462893H" has been added to your sandbox merchant account. The difference between that transaction and your others is that this one is a Sale transaction so there's nothing further to capture. The other transactions you did are authorizations that you had to later capture. This transaction would show in your list of transactions on your dashboard (per your screen shot) if you expanded the results.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Cory i send payment in paypal activity and after that i send response "confirm.toJSONObject().toString()" and "confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject().toString(4)" to my server for verification. On my server i verify from those response and after i do capture to get detail capture such as "state capture". If capture sate is complete then i update state of order product.
you can view my code on server here: https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-4k4wzPaLCbg/U_6UAc_kDLI/AAAAAAAACug/1J5d6XW6ubE/w963-h686-no/pay.png

what is wrong?

Comment: There's nothing wrong other than for the transaction in question, you are setting the initial intent as sale instead of authorization.  If you are doing auth/capture then you need to set the original intent as such. In your mSDK code you need to set PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE instead of PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE.

Comment: yes, i set paypal with PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE, and after i send response of api paypal to my server for check capture.

in my app, i send payment, after i receive response from api paypal.
i continue send this response to my server.
After that, i do capture from this response and get detail capture on my server.
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-4k4wzPaLCbg/U_6UAc_kDLI/AAAAAAAACug/1J5d6XW6ubE/w963-h686-no/pay.png
my final purpose that i want to know money are tranfered in my account paypal.